# Is it possible to specify multiple values for failure condition (F=) using Hydra?

Tags: brute-force, hydra

I want to brute-force a site using Hydra (`https-post-form`) that I don't know valid login credentials for, so I cannot specify a value for success condition (`S=`).

Failed logins result  in a redirect to one of two different failure pages with no words in common.

How can I specify multiple values to `F=`, e.g., `F=(fail)|(tak)` (regular expression)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming Hydra was compiled with PCRE (regular expression) support, the pattern you supply should be treated as a regular expression.  You should be able to use `|` as a pattern "or" operator.

Here's the relevant source code: https://github.com/vanhauser-thc/thc-hydra/blob/eb064c4222964ecac9dc757ad8c847b130c43deb/hydra-http-form.c#L563-L567

You can tell if Hydra was *not* compiled with PCRE support because it will specifically mention "regex support" on the "These services were not compiled" list: https://github.com/vanhauser-thc/thc-hydra/blob/eb064c4222964ecac9dc757ad8c847b130c43deb/hydra.c#L2142-L2146

If you don't have PCRE support, you'll need to recompile Hydra from the repository.

Comment: Thank you. How can I check if Hydra was compiled with PCRE by starting it up (where to look)?

Comment: When you run Hydra with the `-h` flag, it'll show you all the available options and all of the unavailable modules.  If you see regular expressions in the unavailable list, then you do not have regular expression support.

Comment: My list is as follows: `These services were not compiled in: afp ncp oracle sapr3.`.  Nothing is said about features, like regular expression, not compiled in?

Comment: @Shuzheng - I don't see what the problem is then.  You should have regular expression support which means supplying a regular expression in your pattern should work fine.  No additional tweaking required.